# Open jquery ui dialog from itemcommand

Tags: vb.net, modal-dialog

I'd like to be able to display iframe content in Jquery UI dialog and not a pop up as I'm currently doing, but I can't seem to find a way of getting this accomplished.

My current solution looks like this:

```
 If e.CommandName = "CustIDCommand" Then
        Dim CustIDButton As LinkButton
        CustIDButton = FindControl("CustIDBtn")

        Dim str As String = "<script language='Javascript'>"
        str = str + "window.open('/secure/CustCC.aspx','newwin','location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=500,height=275,left=400,top=300')"
        str = str + "</script>"

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "win", str)
        Session("CustID") = e.CommandArgument

    End If
```

An ID number is passed so the CustCC.aspx page displays the correct data. All works fine, but I'd like to load this page in a modal and not a pop up.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
 $("#somediv").load(url).dialog({modal:true});
```

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: I'm not sure how I invoke this? Forgive my lack of knowledge. I currently have a link button in a asp:DetailsView 'code'

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:linkbutton ID="CustIDBtn" runat="server" CommandName="CustIDCommand" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CustID") %>' CausesValidation="false">Customer ID</asp:linkbutton>
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

This fires the above from an ItemCommand